# How do I create this design in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, image, dart

I see this design a ton in apps but have no idea what it is called. It is a super easy to do design but I need your help figuring out the name. Thanks!

I drew it below:
[image]
Basically, it is a slider, but instead of a circle or any other junk a slider usually has, it is 2 boxes, and when Option 1 is selected, the box appears over option 1. When you select option 2, the box slides over to show that option 2 is selected. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  Cupertino Sliding Segmented Control In Flutter. It will provide you with the same result that exacts you want. Check the link for more details. https://medium.flutterdevs.com/cupertino-sliding-segmented-control-in-flutter-ac059963ca70